# OSX Eclipse: No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I have installed Java 1.8.0.25 JDK on OSX 10.10. When trying to open eclipse (64Bit) I get the following error message:

> **A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse.**
>
> No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following
>   locations:
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.8.0.25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java

But when I check my paths all works fine...

```
export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home)"
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home


$ /usr/libexec/java_home
 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home

$ /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/
Home/  MacOS/ 

$ /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/
bin/     db/      include/ jre/     lib/     man/     

$ /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/
appletviewer    jarsigner       javafxpackager  jcmd            jhat            jmc             jstack          keytool         policytool      schemagen       unpack200       
extcheck        java            javah           jconsole        jinfo           jps             jstat           native2ascii    rmic            serialver       wsgen           
idlj            javac           javap           jdb             jjs             jrunscript      jstatd          orbd            rmid            servertool      wsimport        
jar             javadoc         javapackager    jdeps           jmap            jsadebugd       jvisualvm       pack200         rmiregistry     tnameserv       xjc             

$ /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

$ ls /usr/bin/java
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    73B 11 Nov 16:56 /usr/bin/java -> /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java

$ "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java" -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

I also edited (added the `-vm` option) the `eclipse.ini` as suggested in many other threads:

```
...
--launcher.defaultAction 
openFile
-vm 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
-vmargs
...
```

But nothing works, I still get the above message. Did anyone have some idea how to fix this?

Comment: I think the `-vm` value in `eclipse.ini` should end with the actual executable, like so: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java`

Comment: tried it, but didn't work

Comment: sometimes i have similar problems, with 64-bit IDE and 32-bit Java installed. might be nothing, but worth a try maybe :)

Comment: eclipse and java are both installed as 64Bit

Comment: The path in your first error message is incorrect, 1.8.0.25.jdk instead of jdk1.8.0_25.jdk, but I assume you actually tried "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java" ? /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin should also work.

Comment: Now I copied the path from terminal and paste it in the info.plist file and it's working again. I don't know how this crappy path got into the info.plist file.

Answer (score 0):

I've had same issue after installing new jdk (and removing old one). Solution was to fix the path to vm in the `eclipse.ini`

See also ENV Variable `$JAVA_HOME` and `/usr/libexec/java_home`

Answer (score -1):

Try re/installing this: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US

I had the same problem. I suspect that it was because some of the Java infrastructure created by Apple was messed up on my mac. The executable restores them, but still pointed everything at the current JDK that I had installed previously.